# How to validate length of received byte array, which is not null terminated?

Tags: c++, pointers, arrays, penetration-testing

I have a C\C++ code that receives a structure over the network, from this form:

```
struct DataStruct
{
int DataLen;
BYTE* Data;
}
```

The code I have runs over `Data` in a loop of `DataLen` times and processes the data.

**...The problem:**

After the code came to security experts for penetration tests, they prepared a fake application which sends this struct with `DataLen` bigger than the real length of `Data`. This causes, of course, an access violation exception.

So, the question is - how can I validate the real length of the received `Data`? Is it possible without changing the structure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you receive this struct? Could you show some code? The data is not included in the struct. Only the pointer value which is useless on other machnies will be transmitted.

Comment: Show the code you use to read the data from the socket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice security experts! I wish my company had a department like that.

Whenever data is received from the network, the network IO reports the number of bytes actually written to the buffer, whether you used `read(2)`, `recv(2)`, or `boost::asio::async_read` or anything else I've seen. Typical use case when there's a "number of bytes to follow" field in the header of your data structure, is to repeatedly call read/recv/etc until that many bytes were received (or until error occurred), and only then it should construct and return your DataStruct (or report error).

Answer (score 2):

You know how much bytes you have received, so just compare it with `DataLen`.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear - this is exactly my problem: I **don't** know how many bytes did I get...

Comment: How's that? Almost any network IO function gives you this information.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible without changing the structure. Data received from TCP/IP socket is plain stream. Logically, it is not divided into packets. Physical packet may contain one or more DataStruct instances, one DataStruct instance can be divided to two or more physical packets. Current information structure can be used only if there are no communication errors or invalid packets.

Answer (score 0):

Corruption is easy if you haven't any intrinsic limitation.

Some protection mechanisms would be:

- Try to `realloc()` the buffer, within some acceptable size (if `Data` is dynamic)
- Exceptions **are** friends: use `SIGSEGV` in `signal(2)`, `signal(7)` and `setjmp(2)` to do some useful *try/catch* code structure. See [Combining setjmp()/longjmp() and Signal Handling](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411/www/NOTES/non-local-goto/sig-1.html) for a quick introduction on this topic. Use `sigaction(2)` to go deeper (by getting the faulty address;).